# Number of articles per page with Blogger

Tags: blogger

My blog limits the display of items to 2 or 3 per page, while I have set the settings to 7 messages per page. 
Here is the blog link: https://rabiereandco.blogspot.fr/

Can you help me resolve this problem please?
Thanks see you soon

Answer (score 0):

Adding Jump Breaks to each post is the only simple solution as auto-pagination has been triggered. To add it, go into the post editor and click the [image: jump break icon in toolbar] to add the jump break, Refer to the screenshot below - 
[image: adding jump break to post]

To directly add the jump break into the HTML of the post, insert the following -

```
<!--more-->
```

As for the reason why Auto-pagination happened in the first place, the reasons for the same are varied. Few common reasons are -

1. Directly copying posts from Microsoft Word. This brings lots of unwanted formatting into the HTML of the post
2. Dragging and Dropping images into post leads to problems because rather than uploading to Blogger it sometimes gets saved in Base64 format inside the post HTML